# TypeError 'str' object is not callable in Python

Tags: python

The command prompt says TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
It highlights these two separate lines of code.

```
height = float(input('Please enter your height input meters(decimals): '))

height = int(input('Please enter your height input inputches(whole number: '))
```

Comment: Did you define a variable named `input` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Those two lines work fine by themselves, so you might have to add more of your code, and check that the problem shows up when running the code in a fresh session. As Ashwini says, creating a variable called `input` looks like a likely cause of this issue.

Comment: yes there's a variable called input

Answer (score 6):

Now you see why you should **never** name a variable after a built-in. ;)

You said yourself that you made a variable named `input` elsewhere in the code.  Judging by your error, you must have done this before those two lines.  Also, you must have made this variable hold a string.

By doing this, you overshadowed the built-in `input`.  This means that, when you get to those two lines, `input` no longer exists as the built-in.  Instead, it is a string.

Finally, placing `(...)` after `input` throws an error because you can't call a string like a function.

Summed up, you can fix the problem by simply picking a different name for that variable besides `input`.

Comment: Thank you! The program runs fine now!

Comment: @oneabdi - Happy to have helped!  Please don't forget to accept my answer (click the check) so that people know this question is answered.